# MultiBytoToWideChar в C++

Tags: c++, unicode, ansi

Как используя функцию MultiBytoToWideChar написать программу, которая из строки ANSI перевести в Unicode.

```
void fran()
{
    string a;
    cout << "Enter word - ";
    cin >> a;
    const char *st = a.c_str();
    printf(" ANSI - ");
    printf(st, "%s", "ANSI Str");
    cout << endl;
    printf("Unicode - ");
    printf(st, L"%s", L"Unicode Str");
    cout << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Функция возвращает число символов, записанных в буфер `wszTarget`. Если `wszTarget==NULL` (или `bufSize==0`), функция возвращает требуемый размер буфера.

```
int AnsiToUtf16(LPCSTR szSource, LPWSTR wszTarget, int bufSize) {
  return ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, szSource, -1, wszTarget, (wszTarget ? bufSize : 0));
}
```

Пример использования:

```
char str[] = "Quick brown fox jumps...";
int n = AnsiToUtf16(str, NULL, 0);  // Получить необходимый размер буфера для строки
LPWSTR wStr = new WCHAR [n];        // Зарезервировать буфер
AnsiToUtf16(str, wStr, n);          // Преобразовать строку
```